# IIS 6 windows authentication and .Net 4.0 website

Tags: iis, .net-4.0, windows-authentication

I cant get a .Net 4 website to windows auth
I'm running IIS 6.0 with a .Net 4.0 website

If I set Basic auth it validates and works.

**Note** the difference between an application and a website, the website does not work, but the application does

If I set the default website to have an application to the same place windows auth works

if I set the website to windows auth it will prompt for my username password, and fail 3 time and then say unauthorised. It does not lock my account

I have enabled .Net 4 on teh web server extensions. 
I have run aspnet_regiis.exe

I have set it to its own app pool, a shared app pool with the application (not website) that works. To use the app pool that worked on the apllication to be solely on the website

I've set the asp.Net version to be 4.

I've looked in the webserver logs and it has this

```
2011-07-11 04:10:17 W3SVC1459592338 172.XX.XX.XX GET / - 123 - 172.XX.XX.XX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+SV1;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 401 2 2148074254
2011-07-11 04:10:23 W3SVC1459592338 172.XX.XX.XX GET / - 123 - 172.XX.XX.XX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+SV1;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 401 1 0
2011-07-11 04:10:23 W3SVC1459592338 172.XX.XX.XX GET / - 123 - 172.XX.XX.XX Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+SV1;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.30;+.NET+CLR+3.0.04506.648;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) 401 1 0
```

Event log is no help

any iedas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some major searching I found this [MS support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215383). It led me to work out that the authentication type was not set, i set it to NTLM and it all worked

cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/WebSite/root/NTAuthenticationProviders "NTLM"

Where WebSite is the ID of your webste taken from IIS